# ReSharper: automatically apply "var" upon semicolon?

Tags: c#, resharper

When I type the semicolon, ReSharper does certain things to the line of code I've just authored.  Can I include in those actions the removing of the explicit type specification (and replacing it with "var")?

```
string foo = ""
```

... and then I type the semicolon, and the line of code is automatically re-written as follows?

```
var foo = "";
```

**EDIT**: I'm using 4.5 -- I'll move to 5.x soon.

Comment: just curious... why would you want that? I would think you would want to go the other way.

Comment: if you want to use type inference everywhere, why not just get into the habit of declaring everything as var?

Comment: I've come to prefer "var", and I commonly will define the new object before I assign it to a variable (using ReSharper, which defaults the declaration of that variable using the explicit type).  I could add an extra keystroke or two to that process, and choose "var" from the ReSharper menu when declaring the variable, but I've got to type the semicolon anyway, and I'd love to see the variable var'd at that point.  I wonder if can make "var" the default option in the declaration type menu that ReSharper presents during the "Refactor to variable" operation....

Comment: The interesting this is that as soon as you type it out this way R# will suggest that you use var; I think this would be a useful feature also. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use "Clean Up Code" in Resharper to make the changes.  But I use var everywhere possible anyway - so it only makes a difference to old code.  I think it is worth getting youyr settings for "Clean Up Code" just right and applying it to all of your code - it means that the style is always consistent and diffs are always consistent.